# How to reload form in c# when button submit in another form is click?

Tags: c#, forms, button, reload

I have a combo box in my C# which is place in form named `frmMain`  which is automatically fill when I add (using button `button1_Click`) a product in my settings form named `frmSettings`. When I click the button `button1_Click` I want to reload the `frmMain` for the new added product will be visible.

I tried using

```
frmMain main = new frmMain();
main.Close();
main.Show();
```

I know this code is so funny but it didn't work. :D

This is windows form!

**EDIT**

Please see this image of my program for better understanding.
This is my `frmMain`
[image]

Here is what my settings `frmSettings` form look like. So, as you can see when I click the submit button I want to make the `frmMain` to reload so that the updated value which I added to the settings will be visible to `frmMain` comboBox.

[image]

Comment: Is there a special reason why you want to reload the whole form? Why don't you update just the combobox?

Comment: you mean adding another button to update the combo box? a separate code? but I want a few buttons in my form, actually I already have one button in my form, so if I add one for update there will be two and I don't like my form loaded with buttons.

Comment: Actually I also have a data grid view which I need to reload to show the updates of my database.

Comment: Just create a private method and set every as you want to be, and call this method in your button click.

Comment: what about using this.Refresh();

Comment: oh really? there is such thing as Refresh()? well, I will try.

Comment: @NetStarter `this.Refresh()` doesn't reset values.

Comment: yeah it doesn't work.

Comment: Now you have totally changed your question

Comment: sorry not so detailed at first, my bad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update: Since you changed your question here is the updated version to update your products

This is your products form:

```
private frmMain main;

public frmSettings(frmMain mainForm)
{
  main = mainForm;
  InitializeComponent();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  main.AddProduct(textBox1.Text);
}
```

It will need the mainform in the constructor to pass the data to it.

And the main form:

```
private frmSettings settings;
private List<string> products = new List<string>();

public frmMain()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  //load products from somewhere
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (settings == null)
  {
    settings = new frmSettings(this);
  }
  settings.Show();
}

private void UpdateForm()
{
  comboBoxProducts.Items.Clear();
  comboBoxProducts.Items.AddRange(products.ToArray());

  //Other updates
}

public void AddProduct(string product)
{
  products.Add(product);
  UpdateForm();
}
```

You then can call `UpdateForm()` from everywhere on you form, another button for example.
This example uses just a local variable to store your products. There are also missing certain checks for adding a product, but I guess you get the idea...

Answer (score 2):

```cs
this.Close();
frmMain main = new frmMain();
main.Show();
```

Comment: It will be helpful if you briefly explain your answer instead of just giving code.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such built in method to set all your values as you desire. As i mentioned in the comment that you should create a method with your required settings of all controls, here is the sample code:

```
private void ReloadForm()
{
    comboBox.ResetText();
    dataGridView.Update();   
    //and how many controls or settings you want, just add them here
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ReloadForm();   //and call that method on your button click
}
```

Comment: I will try that but I dont want to reset the comboBox just want to reload it.

Comment: First give it a try, then ask. This will just reload and remove user selection from item, not clear the items. If you want to clear the items, then use `comboBox1.Items.Clear()`.

Comment: @Jayseer what dou you mean by "update"? What behaviour do you want to provide?

Comment: I have a separate form for my settings.

Comment: Where is your data coming from into the gridview? From any DB?

Comment: If you are using `TableAdapter` and `BindingSource` to retrieve data from DB and fill it into the gridview then use this with your names `this.productsTableAdapter.Fill(this.DataSet.products);`

Answer (score 1):

Try out this code.

```
this.Refresh();
Application.Doevents();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
this.Refresh();
Refresh();
this.Hide();
frmScholars ss = new frmScholars();
ss.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

you want to Invalidate the form

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/598t492a.aspx

Answer (score 0):

IF you are looking to refresh page from usercontrol .Here is expample where i amrefreshing form from usercontrol 
Find the form in which this reload button is.
Then Call invalidiate tab control and refresh it.

```
Dim myForm As Form = btnAuthorise.FindForm()

For Each c As Control In myForm.Controls
                If c.Name = "tabControlName" Then
                    DirectCast(c, System.Windows.Forms.TabControl).Invalidate()
                    DirectCast(c, System.Windows.Forms.TabControl).Refresh() 'force the call to the drawitem event
                End If
 Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Not required reload for entire form. Just create a function for form initialise.
you can call this function any time. This will refresh the form.

```
private void acc_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     form_Load();           
}

public void form_Load()
{
    // write form initialise codes example listView1.Clear();...
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //edit account
{
    //Do something then refresh form
    form_Load(); 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to automatically update the value of the other form when you click the button from another one you can use timer control. Just set the timer to 0.5s in order to update the form fast

Answer (score -1):

I think that, by calling the `frmMain_load(sender,e)` when you are clicking the button should reload the form.

You may also try to `Invalidate()` the form just like @Nahum said.